# Handling Migrations in a Python/Django App When Deploying from Native System Packages

Tags: python, deployment, deb

After reading this fantastic article by Hynek Schlawack (http://hynek.me/articles/python-app-deployment-with-native-packages/) on utilizing native system packages for Python web-app deployment, I've begun investigating its usage within our environment. However, I'd like to pose the idea of migrations inside a package to people and gather some opinions before delving too deep down the rabbit hole.

Is anyone else using the native-package deployment method described by Hynek? and if so, how do you handle DB migrations? Does it make sense to use a `postinst` hook/script to automate the migration?

Any ideas/help is appreciated.

Cheers,
David.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense to trigger the migrations  in the `postinst` script. However, take into consideration the Database migration process can become really tricky, especially if you're using automated deployment on production system. Consider creating a staging environment to test every deploy before using on production.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, That's pretty much what I'd figured (test+stage-deploy before prod), but I wanted to check others ideas too. I guess if the end-goal is to "automate" deployments, then automating the migrations too would be good. Thanks again.